# What governs whether I see a post in the Close Votes review queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I answered a question, and when my answer posted I saw there was a close vote on it. I thought that was odd, so I clicked Close to see the reason. I then clicked Cancel and, since I disagreed, headed to the Review Queue. On this low traffic site, I knew I could find the post and click Leave Open.

But the post wasn't shown to me. I cleared the queue. Does some part of the system think I already voted on that post? I don't think the fact I answered it comes into play.

Comment: I've often noticed that it takes several minutes for questions to enter the queue, whether or not I load the dialog.

Comment: There's at least a 15 minute delay *after the question is asked*, @nathan.

Comment: @Shog9 or edited? I edited it when I answered it, 16 minutes ago and now I see it in the queue...

Comment: Which site, @kate?

Comment: @Shog9 travel, though I doubt it's relevant.

Comment: Just makes it faster for me to see what's happening while I'm on mobile. In this case, the question was held up in low quality review until you intervened - I'll try to write up a more detailed answer in just a bit.

Comment: hm, the plot thickens, did not consider the possibility it was hanging out in another queue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The close vote was added just seconds after you posted your answer. Roughly 15 minutes later, the question was added to the close queue. The system imposes this delay to give folks a chance to fix problems before the reviewers see it.

As the comment thread above indicates, I don't even remember how this stuff works anymore without referring to the code. Therefore, I will list the current criteria for adding questions to close review:

1. When a question has pending close votes or flags that are older than 15 minutes, and
2. The question is not locked or deleted, and
3. There's no open bounty on the question, and
4. There's no existing close review task newer than the oldest pending vote or the oldest flag that is *either* active or was completed by the addition of a pending vote, and
5. There's no pending Triage review task for the question (on sites where Triage is enabled - currently just Stack Overflow)

...then a new close review task will be created.

The 15-minute age restriction for flags is what tripped me up here: for most other queues, that age restriction applies to the age of the *post*. I don't recall why this is different for close review; it's possible this was unintentional.